# Django migrating app without migrations

Tags: python, django

I've created a new Django project consisting of a single app. I thought Django would only migrate an app only if its migrations exist.

The first time I run `python manage.py migrate`, Django would create tables for my app as well(I've created models.py for my app)

I haven't run `python manage.py makemigrations app` or `python manage.py makemigrations` till this time.

I would get the following output on running `python manage.py migrate`:

```
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Creating table app_model
```

This is not what I want, because the next time I actually make migrations for the app and run migrate, Django would complain that the tables already exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the migrations, and fake the first migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

This will skip any initial migration for which the tables have already been created.

Django (pre 1.9) will synchronize any apps that don't have migrations, see the docs on [migrate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-migrate):

> The behavior of this command changes depending on the arguments provided:
>
> - No arguments: All migrated apps have all of their migrations run, and **all unmigrated apps are synchronized with the database,**

Comment: I know I can do this. I'm just worried why is Django migrating my apps without having created migrations for them. This is required because I need to check migrations file before applying them which I'm not able to do here.

Comment: That's how Django operates pre-1.9. If you want to test the migration you can always migrate back using `migrate <app_name> zero`, then rerun the migration.

Comment: Can you point me towards this documentation and add your comment to the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save `migrations` for app, wich you already migrate. You can change one field in model, then `makemigrations this_app` -> `migrate` and return has been again with `makemigrations` and `migrate`. But I dont understand why you want this.

Comment: I don't want Django to migrate any app without me having made migrations for it. That's what I want.